# MyFXBook login implementation

Tags: json, flutter, api, authentication

I am trying to connect my flutter project login page to myfxbook backend so that users can sign in from my app and it is recorded on the myfxbook database. I have designed the login page and the api page but I seem to be getting a lot of issues from the api setup page. This is the code to the api.dart file:`import 'dart:convert';

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MyFxbookApi {
  static const String _baseUrl = 'https://www.myfxbook.com/api/login.json';
  Future<bool> login(String email, String password) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), body: {
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      final String success = responseData['success'].toString();
      final String error = responseData['error'];
      final String session = responseData['session'];

      if (success == true) {
        // Login successful
        print('Login successful, session: $session');
        return true;
      } else {
        // Login failed
        print('Login failed, error: $error');
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // Error occurred
      print('Error occurred, status code: ${response.statusCode}');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the errors I get:

```
 `E/flutter ( 9959): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 9959): #0      MyFxbookApi.login (package:audeet/api/myfxbookapi.dart:16:20)
E/flutter ( 9959): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9959): #1      _LoginPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:audeet/Screens/login_page.dart:92:29)
E/flutter ( 9959): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9959):

I've tried a lot of different approaches but couldn't wrap my head around it. The app runs perfectly but when I click on the login button, It loses everything  and gives the errors. These are the errors: 
E/flutter ( 9959): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 9959): #0      MyFxbookApi.login (package:audeet/api/myfxbookapi.dart:16:20)
E/flutter ( 9959): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9959): #1      _LoginPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:audeet/Screens/login_page.dart:92:29)
E/flutter ( 9959): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9959):`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `success` variable is a `String` and you are comparing with a `bool`.

Try to change this line

```
final bool success = responseData['success'].toString() == 'true';
```